# Propel, selecting just one column

Tags: propel, propel2

I am trying to run a query in propel that runs an aggregate function (SUM).

**My Code**

```
$itemQuery = SomeEntity::Create();
$itemQuery->withColumn('SUM(SomeColumn)', someColumn)
      ->groupBy(SomeForeignKey);
```

**Problem**

It should theoretically return the sum of every group of items but the problem is propel tries to fetch all columns, and also appends a bunch of other columns to the group by clause. This results in an unexpected categorisation and therefore the sum is incorrect.

Is there anyway to make propel fetch just the column I am running the aggregation function on so that the group by statement works as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a select statement for the column and the foreign key:

```
$itemQuery = SomeEntity::Create();
$itemQuery->select(array(SomeColumn, SomeForeignKey));
$itemQuery->withColumn('SUM(SomeColumn)', someColumn);
$itemQuery->groupBy(SomeForeignKey);
```